# How to make sure the listener is finished before returning a value in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a function that returns a list that contains the ids of documents.
For reading the data out of the databse (Cloud Firestore) I use an OnCompleteListener.
This is my Code so far:

```
private fun getInvolvedChannels(): MutableList<String> {
    var involvedList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(currentUserId!!).collection("engagedChatChannels").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener ( object : OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                override fun onComplete(task: Task<QuerySnapshot>) {
                    task.result.documents.forEach {
                        val currentChannelId = it.id.toString()
                        involvedList.add(currentChannelId)
                    }
                }
            })
   involvedList = buildChatChannelString(involvedList)
    return involvedList
}
```

The reading part already works fine. The problem is that the list gets returned before the Listener even red one Id. So it always returns an empty list. Where is my Error? How can I make sure the Listener finished before I return the List?

Comment: get() is asynchronous.  It returns immediately, and the results of the query are delivered to your callback some time later.  You should do all your subsequent processing after the callback is invoked.  You can read more about why all Firebase APIs are async in this blog: https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042961/how-does-firebase-completion-callbacks-work-in-kotlin/51045463)** out.